# Changing parameters such that it takes an array of parameters instead of single parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

Looking at the script below it works well in terms of starting and stopping VM's in Azure, the problem here is that when you present it with a list of VM's, it assumes they are all in thesame subscription. Or deployment solution works best with one liner parameters.

I am trying to rewrite the script such that it takes the following parameters as an array and loops through them one at a time based on the following `$VMName,$ResourceGroupName,$AzureSubscriptionID,$Action` .

`("$VMName,$ResourceGroupName,$AzureSubscriptionID,$Action","$VMName,$ResourceGroupName,$AzureSubscriptionID,$Action")`

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    # Specify the name of the Virtual Machine, or use the asterisk symbol "*" to affect all VMs in the resource group
    $VMName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    # Optionally specify Azure Subscription ID
    $AzureSubscriptionID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet("Start", "Stop")]
    # Specify desired Action, allowed values "Start" or "Stop"
    $Action
)

Write-Output "Script started at $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"

# temporarily hide Warning message (see Issue #2 in Github)
$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
# explicitly load the required PowerShell Az modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts,Az.Compute
# re-set WarningPreference to show Warning Messages
$WarningPreference = "Continue"

$errorCount = 0

# connect to Azure, suppress output
try {
    $null = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = "Error connecting to Azure: " + $_.Exception.message
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
    throw $ErrorMessage
    exit
}

# select Azure subscription by ID if specified, suppress output
if ($AzureSubscriptionID) {
    try {
        $null = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID $AzureSubscriptionID    
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = "Error selecting Azure Subscription ($AzureSubscriptionID): " + $_.Exception.message
        Write-Error $ErrorMessage
        throw $ErrorMessage
        exit
    }
}

# check if we are in an Azure Context
try {
    $AzContext = Get-AzContext
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = "Error while trying to retrieve the Azure Context: " + $_.Exception.message
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
    throw $ErrorMessage
    exit
}
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AzContext.Subscription)) {
    $ErrorMessage = "Error. Didn't find any Azure Context. Have you assigned the permissions according to 'CustomRoleDefinition.json' to the Managed Identity?"
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
    throw $ErrorMessage
    exit
}

if ($VMName -eq "*") {
    try {
        # if "*" was given as the VMName, get all VMs in the resource group
        $VMs = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = "Error getting VMs from resource group ($ResourceGroupName): " + $_.Exception.message

        Write-Error $ErrorMessage
        throw $ErrorMessage
        exit
    }
    
}
else {
    try {
        # get only the specified VM
        $VMs = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = "Error getting VM ($VMName) from resource group ($ResourceGroupName): " + $_.Exception.message
        Write-Error $ErrorMessage
        throw $ErrorMessage
        exit
    }
    
}

# Loop through all specified VMs (if more than one). The loop only executes once if only one VM is specified.
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    switch ($Action) {
        "Start" {
            # Start the VM
            try {
                Write-Output "Starting VM $($VM.Name)..."
                $null = $VM | Start-AzVM -ErrorAction Stop -NoWait
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
                Write-Error "Error starting the VM $($VM.Name): " + $ErrorMessage
                # increase error count
                $errorCount++
                Break
            }
        }
        "Stop" {
            # Stop the VM
            try {
                Write-Output "Stopping VM $($VM.Name)..."
                $null = $VM | Stop-AzVM -ErrorAction Stop -Force -NoWait
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
                Write-Error "Error stopping the VM $($VM.Name): " + $ErrorMessage
                # increase error count
                $errorCount++
                Break
            }
        }    
    }
}

$endOfScriptText = "Script ended at $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
if ($errorCount -gt 0) {
    throw "Errors occured: $errorCount `r`n$endofScriptText"
}
Write-Output $endOfScriptText
```

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you would like an example command line invocation to look like - the parameters are probably going to get quite long and unwieldy when you start specifying multiple combinations of virtual machine names, subscription ids and resource groups / actions... Is taking the list of parameters for each virtual machine from a data file (e.g. a csv / json file) a viable option instead?

Comment: thank you for the reply, my parameter list isn't much at this stage, with the way the script is, I have to setup 3 deployment jobs for 3 VM's in 3 different subs, if I have it such that all parameters are in an array, then its a single job albeit with a long list of parameters . If the list of VM grows, then we can have a Ps script file that lists them all.

Comment: Putting the parameters into a .csv file might make processing much easier.

Comment: the best way to do this is an array of hashtables, then you can use splatting: `$params | ForEach-Object { Test-Func @_ }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Do you have examples please ? and will this support the use of a file in future? Looking at writing this once such that to use the deployment tool, I can pass in one liners and in future if the VM list is a lot, I can pass in a file with a list.

Answer (score 1):

> Changing parameters such that it takes an array of parameters instead of single parameters.

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to accept an `array of parameters` and loop through them one at a time.

```
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string[]]$VMParams = @(
            "VMName,ResourceGroupName,<SUB-ID>,Action",
            "VMName,ResourceGroupName,<SUB-ID>,Action"
        )
    )
    
    Write-Output "Script started at $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
    
    # temporarily hide Warning message (see Issue #2 in Github)
    $WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    # explicitly load the required PowerShell Az modules
    Import-Module Az.Accounts,Az.Compute
    # re-set WarningPreference to show Warning Messages
    $WarningPreference = "Continue"
    
    $errorCount = 0
    
    # connect to Azure, suppress output
    try {
        $null = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = "Error connecting to Azure: " + $_.Exception.message
        Write-Error $ErrorMessage
        throw $ErrorMessage
        exit
    }
    
    # Loop through each parameter set in $VMParams
    foreach ($VMParam in $VMParams) {
        $Params = $VMParam -split ","
        
        $VMName = $Params[0]
        $ResourceGroupName = $Params[1]
        $AzureSubscriptionID = $Params[2]
        $Action = $Params[3]
    
        # select Azure subscription by ID if specified, suppress output
        if ($AzureSubscriptionID) {
            try {
                $null = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID $AzureSubscriptionID    
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorMessage = "Error selecting Azure Subscription ($AzureSubscriptionID): " + $_.Exception.message
                Write-Error $ErrorMessage
                throw $ErrorMessage
                exit
            }
        }
    
        # check if we are in an Azure Context
        try {
            $AzContext = Get-AzContext
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorMessage = "Error while trying to retrieve the Azure Context: " + $_.Exception.message
            Write-Error $ErrorMessage
            throw $ErrorMessage
            exit
        }
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AzContext.Subscription)) {
            $ErrorMessage = "Error. Didn't find any Azure Context. Have you assigned the permissions according to 'CustomRoleDefinition.json' to the Managed Identity?"
            Write-Error $ErrorMessage
            throw $ErrorMessage
            exit
        }
    
        try {
            # Get the VM based on the specified parameters
            $VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorMessage = "Error getting VM ($VMName) from resource group ($ResourceGroupName): " + $_.Exception.message
            Write-Error $ErrorMessage
            throw $ErrorMessage
            exit
        }
    
        switch ($Action) {
            "Start" {
                # Start the VM
                try {
                    Write-Output "Starting VM $($VM.Name)..."
                    $null = $VM | Start-AzVM -ErrorAction Stop -NoWait
                }
                catch {
                    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
                    Write-Error "Error starting the VM $($VM.Name): " + $ErrorMessage
                    # increase error count
                    $errorCount++
                    Break
                }
            }
            "Stop" {
                # Stop the VM
                try {
                    Write-Output "Stopping VM $($VM.Name)..."
                    $null = $VM | Stop-AzVM -ErrorAction Stop -Force -NoWait
                }
                catch {
                    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
                    Write-Error "Error stopping the VM $($VM.Name): " + $ErrorMessage
                    # increase error count
                    $errorCount++
                    Break
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    Write-Output "------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "Script ended at $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
```

This `PowerShell` script takes an array of parameter sets `$VMParams` as input. Each parameter set contains the `VM name`, `resource group name`, `Azure subscription ID`, and action to be performed (**start or stop**).

**Output:**

[image]